# Bundling of independent or dependent js files using webpack and exposing methods to other js files or html <script> code

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-4

I have simple three files.
one add.js

```
function add(x,y){
  return x+y
}
```

two sub.js

```
function sub(x,y){
 return x-y
}
```

three calc.js

```
console.log("Add : "+add(5,1))
console.log("Sub : "+sub(5,1))
```

entry.js

```
import 'add.js'
import 'sub.js'
import 'main.js'
```

after webpack when i see.

it tells add method is not found.

my webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
 mode:'development',
 entry: './entry.js',
 output: {
   filename: 'main.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
};
```

why the methods are not exposed to main.js.

if i add window.add = add and window.sub = sub then it is exposed, with plain js why the methods are not exposed by main.js.

The purpose of asking is i am having plenty of old js files which as multiple functions and inside html code also these functions are called.

Is there any simple configuration in webpack to expose these function?

Comment: what is the expected behavior when you say 'not exposed?' do you want to do something like import from 'main.js'?

Comment: Like the add method in add.js is scoper within add.js if we want to use it in calc.js we have to import the function in calc.js as per webpack. but our codes are very old. we just put a script tag in html when calc.js us inclucded we have included add.js. now i want to bundle all the js files in script tag. the bundle.is created successful but the.method scope is not exposed to other js. until for all methods in a js is included as window.< methodname> to call it from html codes and other js.